# How much space Window Explorer Indexing takes up?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, windows-11, windows-search, search-indexing

If I were to Index entire OS partition, how much space would Indexing take up?
Indexing is only properties. Though I'm curious how much more space it will take with Properties and Content.

Comment: The index size depends on the number of files on a partition

Comment: How much space per file then?

Answer (score 1):

Do not index a whole drive - just what you need (common folders). Outlook and Documents are normally included.

It does not (vast majority of the time) make sense to index windows; programdata; programfiles and those kind of files. What you need to index are folders and files that make sense when you see the search results.

Read this:

[Windows Search and Indexing](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/windows-search-platform/configuration-and-settings/)

**My index is just short of 200,000 items and take up just over 2 GB of space**:

Index is stored at:  C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Search\Data\Applications\Windows

Main items in the document:

**The Good Old Control Panel Applet:**

> Inside the indexing options dialog you’ll find an array of settings
> and options that you’re able to configure.

**Indexed Data Types**

> In case you were ever curious on how the service decides what to put
> in the index this dialog shows you the list it uses to determine what
> data gets indexed. What you see right away is a list of “Included
> Locations” and “Excluded Locations”, and these behave exactly as they
> read. The indexing service contains a master list of what we call
> “scopes” that identify the file system paths the service will crawl,
> which paths we will ignore, and other data types that applications
> have registered on the machine for indexing.

**File Types**

> Now let’s move over to the File Types tab. You’ll noticed there is a
> very large list of extensions along with descriptions for each of
> them. These are the list of registered extensions in the system, which
> are done in the registry through the shell layer. Every extension in
> the system contains a property handler to programmatically read and
> write to. These can either be created and deployed by an installed
> application or they can be a system one. Extensions also may or may
> not have a corresponding file filter, which are the IFilters discussed
> in the previous article. These filters can be registered with a given
> file extension in order to help the indexing service extract the
> necessary pieces of content out from that file so you can search it.

There are lots of details in the article I posted and it is worth your time to read and understand it.

Here is a summary screen shot.

[image: Windows Indexing Options]